# Rails 4 with minimum dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies

I'm writing a Rails 4 app from scratch and I want it to be as independent as possible. For example, if I'm writing an authorization code, I don't want to use bcrypt gem.

So what are the absolute essential gems for Rails to work visually and technically?

As an example, I'd just like to create a simple `scaffold user first_name last_name` that I can see on my browser and make simple create, read, update, destroy operations from the browser.

Comment: If I understood your question, then Rails already comes with a default Gemfile that allows you to do all these things. Is that what you mean, or do you want to cut your Gemfile even further?

Comment: I want to cut my Gemfile further to the extreme essentials. Everything that is not necessary for the above scaffold example to work needs to go.

Comment: What for? So you can introduce more bugs and vulnerabilities in your code? Maybe go for PHP then?

Comment: If you have no constructive input, please don't reply. I will gladly use the security-essential gems and whatnot, I was rather referring to all "extra gems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails 4 app comes bundled with a lot of gems. Most of them are very good things to keep, but if you really care about it:

- `rails` - That should be self explanatory.
- `sqlite3` - You need a database gem. Personally I use `mysql`, but it's totally up to you and the comparisons are beyond the scope of this question.
- `sass-rails` - this is used in precompiling assets from stylesheets. `Sass` provides a lot of nice utilities, including the ability to nest CSS rules that make your stylesheets both more readable and maintainable, but if you don't want it, you don't need it.
- `uglifier` - if you don't care about sending minified JS (as in you don't care about the size of your request responses) you can get rid of this. I definitely wouldn't recommend that though.
- `coffee-rails` - if you don't want to use coffee script you can get rid of this.
- `jquery-rails` - most modern sites use some kind of javascript library, be it jquery, prototype, angular, Node.js, or something else. It's up to you, but I would at least use something.
- `turbolinks` - rails 4 by default uses javascript to load each page, which speeds up the page load time significantly. You need to read more [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) if you're going to get rid of this.
- `jbuilder` - if you don't care about responding with jsons, you can get rid of this (definitely don't recommend)
- `sdoc` - if you don't want documentation, you can remove it.
- `capistrano` - this is for helping with deployment, and I would suggest using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will click your answer as accepted but first I'll test will it run properly in production.